# why we find dual solution in place of single solution of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my ans is that in single solution we cannot check there stability so in dual solution we have to find one upper and lower branch solution and then we checked taht which one is more stable in above two branch solution if lower is stable and upper is not then we cant follow upper and similary vice versa.so please comment that my answer is correct or not.

Comment: What is a dual solution in this context?

Comment: "dual means that we used any numerical technique and find a two solution of any ordinary differential equation .but my question is just i want a correct answer if some one ask me that why we find dual solution in place of single solution .the answer which i mentioned above this answer i got from our own point of view that,s why i want that am i is correct or not if not then give me a correct reason sir thank u in advanced."

Comment: That didn't answer my question, can you give some example?